# Function that isolates values of a variable and attaches individual functions to each

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a variety of anchor tags and input buttons that trigger a variety of alert messages.  The alert messages are already built as functions.  The triggers have various classes.  I've created separate scripts to get each of these triggers to fire their individual functions.  Now I'm trying to streamline this process by building a function that will dynamically attach the proper alert message function with the right trigger class.

I've created an allTriggers variable (as shown below) in which I can load all of the classes for each trigger.

```
var allTriggers = $('.firstColumn a, .uploadAttachment, .tabGroup .tab a, .checkForChanges')
```

No here is the part I'm struggling with.  I want to build a function that attaches the proper alert message (function) to the proper trigger

In other word...

if the value of allTriggers = the trigger with the class .uploadAttachment, then perform the function uploadFunction.

if the value of allTriggers = the trigger with the class .firstColumn a, then perform the function removeMessageFunction.

and so on.

I want to do this so that a programmer can come in later and add triggers and alerts as needed to this simple var and function and it will fill in the blanks across the rest of the script that I already have working.

The function I'm working on is something similar to the one below, but this isn't working

```
function popupOKFunction() {
        if (allTriggers == '.firstColumn a') {
                removeMessageFunction ();
        }
        if (allTriggers == '.uploadAttachment') {
                uploadFunction ();
        } 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use two facts about JavaScript: 1) one can use (almost) any string as a name of an object's property; 2) functions are first-class citizens and may be used just as (again - almost) most values would.

So what can be useful to you is not a function - but an object:

```
var controlHandlers = {
  '.firstColumn a': removeMessageFunction,
  '.uploadAttachment': uploadFunction,
  ...
};
```

... then you may iterate over it with something like...

```
for (var selector in controlHandlers) {
   $(selector).click(controlHandlers[selector]);  
}
```

**UPDATE:** the same approach will be useful if you eventually decide to use just a single function - but with different messages to be shown: these messages will be send in this function as param. Like this:

```
var controlMessages = {
  '.firstColumn a': "Do not ever touch this link! Ever!",
  '.uploadAttachment': "Now I'm angry!",
};
...
for (var selector in controlMessages) {
  $(selector).click(function() { 
    alertingFunction(controlMessages[selector]);
  });
}
```

`alertingFunction` in this case should be defined as taking a single parameter - message to be shown.

Comment: thanks raina77ow...that headed me in the right direction.  i just needed to play with the for function in order make it fit my use case, but the var idea really helped.